# How Sessions are calculated when applying Advanced Segment

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Suppose i have a product home page for eg http://domain.com/products/sonymobile.com and i need to find people who have visited the above product page in an session.

So when i apply an Advanced segment including page as above. The tricky part is how the sessions are calculated?

a) Does google count only the sessions wherein the session starts from "http://domain.com/products/sonymobile.com"

OR

b) the page can come anywhere in the whole session.

[Advanced Segment Image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you build your segment. If its scope is session, the answer is b). It seems that you are confused about an issue like https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2934985?hl=en , but it's not about segments.